# Load a user object via login form name field

Tags: 6, users, authentication-authorization

I'm trying to check if a user account has been disabled for LDAP before the user completes the login process using a custom form validator.

What has me stuck is how I would use user_load to load the user object of the person logging in via the login form. I'm not sure how I would structure the form array within the user_load function.

What I currently have is:

```
$account = user_load($form_state['values']->name);
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [user_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/6) function in D6 you have to use pass the $user_info array like ,

```
 $account = user_load(array('name' => $form_state['values']->name))
```

Answer (score 0):

$user = user_load(array('name'=>'username'));